# How to suppress logs for ContextHandler in spark

Tags: apache-spark

In my log4j file, I have already added the following log level for ContextHandler,

but, ContextHandler stuff still prints the log.

```
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler=WARN
log4j.logger.org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler=WARN
```

I would ask how to suppress ContextHandler logs.

Answer (score 3):

Adding this to your log4j.properties should help:

`log4j.category.org.spark_project.jetty=WARN`

**Update:** Since Spark 3.0 it's changed to

`log4j.category.org.sparkproject.jetty=WARN` (thanks [@ivan-vergiliev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596167/ivan-vergiliev))

Comment: Starting with Spark 3.0, the package got renamed to `sparkproject` (no underscore) so the right config setting becomes

`log4j.category.org.sparkproject.jetty=WARN`

instead.

Comment: for lo4j2.properties what should be the property name

Comment: * log4j2.properties starting with Spark 3.3.x